# What can someone access on my iPhone if they set up their iCloud account on my device?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

Here is the situation: I am going to meet someone, who will set up their iCloud account on my device.

Is there any way to remove their iCloud account from my iPhone?
Can they find me if I let them set up their iCloud account on my iPhone for 15-30 minutes?
Can they access my iPhone's secret information that may allow them to find the phone's location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can not remove their iCloud account without their password.
2. The can access everything you allow to synchronise with their iCloud account.
3. You can turn off all iCloud settings except Find My iPhone without their password.
4. They can also lock your iPhone and or erase your iPhone.

So basically the can find your iPhone at any given time.

When your transaction is done make sure they remove their iCloud account completely!